# In Unity can I have a banner and an interstitial ad on same scene?

Tags: admob, unity-game-engine, ads, banner-ads

I have developed a game and I was just wondering if its possible to have both the banner and interstitial ad in same game scene in Unity for more revenue

Comment: i think if you have another process in progress and system is busy, you cannot call function show for other model of advertisement

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06lbjMFqWpg for a tutorial on how to have both of them in the same scene

Answer (score 0):

Banner ad is not supposed to be hidden & must not have an overlay either so the moment you try to show and interstitial over it, banner will be paused for time being. A unity scene is often paused when you display an interstitial ad specially if its video ad.

Maybe u can try 2 different ads sdks for better results.

Too many ads are however never recommended, it drops your user retention significantly if user uninstall rate goes up which will result in reduced.

Additionally banner ads seem to hang almost any game sdk scene including unity occasionally specially during refresh so it might result in memory overload & crash too.

Another recommendation i can have is, give it a try but control this config remotely so that you optimise it based on need. Making revenue from ads is all about right ad at right place. Its never about how many ads you show, its all about eCPM & ARPU.